# Connect to Outlook.com IMAP using OAuth 2.0 android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, imap, hotmail

I'm trying to connect to outlook IMAP using OAuth2 under android however I'm struggling a bit with how to implement it. the AccountManager.getAuthToken(account, authTokenType, null, activity, callback, null) returns a null token, so I could not go further.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve it? In the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440163.aspx, you can see some information, but it seems not enough.